# Points at infinity and rational points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I was reading through the research paper *Rational Points on Curves* by Michael Stoll and there was this line written

> We observe that a curve and its smooth projective model only differ in a computable finite set of points (coming from points at infinity and from singularities).

I have no problems with understanding that the projectivization of an affine curve only differs by a finite set of points, let's call it $S$. However, based on what was written, if my initial curve is a smooth affine curve, then $S$ only consists of points at infinity. For these questions, we let the smooth affine curve be defined over a number field $k$.

**Question 1.** What is known about the size of $S$? For example, for the "affine part" $C$ of an elliptic curve given by
$$C:y^2 = x^3+ax+b,$$ for $a,b \in k$, its projective closure via the inclusion $\mathbb{A}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$ is
$$Y^2Z = X^3+aXZ^2+bZ^3.$$
Since the curve $C$ was already smooth, its projective closure coincides with its smooth projective model. This new projective model differ from $C$ by the point $[0:1:0]$, hence $|S| = 1$.

**Question 2.** Are there ways to determine if the points in $S$ are $k$-rational?

Comment: For Question 1 you can't say anything. If $X$ is a smooth projective curve and $S$ is any finite set of closed points (nonempty) then $X-S$ is affine. For Question 2, this seems hard/not doable. What would a hypothetical answer even look like?

Comment: @AlexYoucis I know that the removal of a nonzero finite number of closed points from a smooth projective curve is affine, but if we projectivize this new affine curve, do we get the original projective curve? It seems to not be true, because from the sentence I quoted, if we start with a smooth affine curve, we are only missing points at infinity compared to its projective model, and not all arbitrary closed points are points at infinity.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Regarding Question 2, I'm not sure if what I'm about to write is correct: Let $E/k$ be given by $y^2 = x^3 + ax+b$ be the affine part of an elliptic curve, then its projective model is given by $Y^2Z=X^3+aXZ^2+bZ^3$, the missing point is $[0:1:0]$ which is a $k$-rational points as its coordinates are contained in $k$. That's why I thought about this question.

Comment: There's a fair amount of distance between that example and what you've written in your post. Your motivating example is an affine curve $X$ which is a closed subvariety of some $\Bbb A^n$ where you take the projective closure and this turns in to the smooth projective model for $X$, but your question doesn't fix an embedding of $X$ in $\Bbb A^n$ and it is frequently the case that the projective closure of an embedded curve is not the smooth projective model for that curve - try $y=x^4$ in $\Bbb A^2$ for instance.

Comment: @KReiser So in my example, I am actually considering the projective closure of the curve under the inclusion $\mathbb{A}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$. For $y = x^4$, I'm guessing that we still take projective closure first, to obtain $YZ^3 = X^4$, and then resolve singularities to obtain the smooth projective model. For my example, the curve was already smooth so no resolution was needed, am I right to say that?

Comment: Perhaps I could have been clearer. The point of the first issue I brought up is that there are parts of your setup which are found in your comments but not your question - this should be fixed with an [edit]. The point of the second issue is that the two processes of "take projective closure" and "take smooth projective model" are different in general and it seems like your question is assuming that they're the same. I'm trying to let you know about these issues so you can fix up your question to get it to a place where you can get an answer. (Answer for your q from last comment: yes.)

Comment: @KReiser Alright I've made some corrections. By the comment from Alex Youcis it seems like my questions wouldn't be going anywhere. From my example, could we say that $[0:1:0]$ is $k$-rational? I think its true because, well, the coordinates are integers, but I think I may be misunderstanding something again.